# ASP.NET Core App on Google Cloud Platform (Linux)

Tags: linux, google-app-engine, asp.net-core, .net-core, google-cloud-platform

We have several intranet ASP.NET applications as parts of erp system running on local company Windows server, but recently decided to move to Linux servers due to low cost of maintenance. I know that it's possible to deploy ASP.NET Core Apps to Google Cloud Platform, but I did not find any info how to setup Linux VM to make deploy possible.(there is only info about setting up Windows VM).

Maybe someone had an experience of deploying asp.net core to linux on Google Cloud Platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [**set up a Linux VM**](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/quickstart-linux) in the GCP Console (on VM instances page) and then deploy your app using that instance, however, Google Cloud Platform [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-aspnet-core-app-to-gcp) offers 4 substitute ways to deploy an **ASP.NET** Core app to GCP.

The simplest one would be to **deploy it from Visual Studio**.

> To deploy your ASP.NET Core app to GCP, you can use [Google Cloud
>   Tools for Visual Studio](https://cloud.google.com/tools/visual-studio/docs/quickstart) extension, which takes care of all the
>   necessary details to deploy your app from right inside the Visual
>   Studio IDE.

Another option would be to **deploy a Framework Dependent Deployment bundle** (see *“Method 2”* in the mentioned documentation).

> This would be the simplest way to deploy your app from the command
>   line.

If you need more control over how your app’s container is built, you can also specify your own Dockerfile to **deploy your app to Google App Engine** with it (see *“Method 3”*).

> This method would be especially helpful if you need to install custom
>   packages in the container, extra tools or need more control over the
>   contents of the container.

Alternatively, if you need more control over your **workloads**, or need to use **protocols** not supported by App Engine, you can use the [**Container Engine**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) (*"Method 4"*).

[**Here**](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-app-engine-aspnetcore/#0) you may find a **step-by-step tutorial** on deploying an ASP.NET Core app to App Engine, which you might want to use as a reference.